# How do I create Rflection generic dao, services, controller?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, reflection

I have Spring Hibernate project that produces JSON from Rest call.  My project structure is attached. These classes are actually meta model of user defined table and properties. User will add table column name and properties using "MyServiceOne' and 'MyServiceTwo' then a DDL will create actual database tables. Now I need to have a generic Dao, Service and Controller that will do the CRUD operation on user table and will generate JSON on Rest call. I am trying to do this by Reflection but I am not able to do it properly. What should be the best solution?

My db configuration is at src/main/webapp/WEB_INF/spring-config.xml

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this for inspiration: https://github.com/danjee/generic-dao

Comment: This actually does not solve my problem. How do I fit this in current structure? Is this possible to do dynamic modelling or it is better to handle the situation with plain JDBC call?